# C - Create two processes and call functions

Tags: c, process, fork

This maybe a simple question but I want to know how to create 2 processes using `fork` and then call a function from both processes. Would it be ok to call the fork() once since it returns a child and a parent?

I also need to know how to set one process to sleep for a certain period of time while the other process is running.

Comment: It sounds like you're more in need of task based parallelism than using fork()

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're actually asking.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have to write a program that creates two processes which will read a file (Both processes read the same file) and saves it's content to a variable. Can this be done with just one simple fork call since I will get a parent and a child process?

Comment: You can turn one process into two with a single `fork` call.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz and may I ask how?

Comment: Just by calling `fork`. That's exactly, and only, what it does.

Comment: The `sleep()` call sends a process to sleep for an integer number of seconds.  The `usleep()` or `nanosleep()` calls can be used to sleep for intervals involving fractions of a second.  The `fork()` function does indeed create a second process (it returns twice, once in the original parent process, and once in the new child process).  That's all there is to it.